# websocket.js:198 WebSocket connection to 'wss://my_progect.herokuapp.com/socket.io/.' failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established

Tags: flask, heroku, websocket, socket.io, flask-socketio

I have a trouble with using flask-socketio. It reterns the above error and I dont now why.

Maybe the problem in Heroku where my web were deployed?
I have the

'Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (BAD REQUEST)'

'websocket.js:87 WebSocket connection to 'wss://my_progect.herokuapp.com/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket&sid=...' failed: '

'POST https://my_progect.herokuapp.com/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=... 400 (BAD REQUEST)'

'GET https://my_progect.herokuapp.com/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=... 400 (BAD REQUEST)'

errors too

My Procfile:

```
web: gunicorn app:app
```

My html import

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/4.0.1/socket.io.js" integrity="sha512-q/dWJ3kcmjBLU4Qc47E4A9kTB4m3wuTY7vkFJDTZKjTs8jhyGQnaUrxa0Ytd0ssMZhbNua9hE+E7Qv1j+DyZwA==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="{{ url_for ('static', filename = 'likes_groups.js') }}"></script>
```

My js code

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

var socket = io.connect(location.protocol + '//' + document.domain + ':' + location.port);

socket.on('connect', () => {
    document.querySelectorAll('button').forEach(button => {
        button.onclick = () => {
            const id = button.dataset.id;
            const choice = button.dataset.choice;

            socket.emit('likes groups', [id, choice]);
        };
    });
});
```

And some of py file

```
socketio = SocketIO(app, async_mode='eventlet')

@app.route('/voting_groups')
@login_required
def voting_groups():
 return render_template('voting_groups.html')

@socketio.on('likes groups')
def likes_groups(data):
   "some code"

port = int(os.environ.get('PORT', 5000))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app, host='0.0.0.0', port=port, debug=True)
```

On local all work without errors but when I deploy project on Heroku it crashe.
I saw that same problems was solved but noone of the solutions to there didnt work for me (but maybe i am a blind)

Thanks

I want to send the users choice to my flask server

Comment: can you try removing the port option? and check the CORS settings as well on socket server

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, sorry, I'm a beginner

Answer (score 0):

Your Procfile should be like this:

```
gunicorn --worker-class eventlet --timeout 9999 --workers 1 wsgi:app
```

Comment: Hi, sorry for so late response. Of course, Im beginner, but it seemed to me that Procfileshould include the elements "web:" and "app:". Am i wrong?

Otherwise, in all these cases - (gunicorn --worker-class eventlet --timeout 9999 --workers 1 wsgi:app) - (web: gunicorn --worker-class eventlet --timeout 9999 --workers 1 wsgi:app) - (web: gunicorn --worker-class eventlet --timeout 9999 --workers 1 app:app)
this error comes out: (at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=flask-test-esheshka.herokuapp.com request_id=1e58a773-b04e-4e75-a80d- fwd="109.252.149.133")

Comment: By the way, I have a little changes in py file (added "port")

Comment: Okey you can ignore other things in proc file. But you must have to mention workers option(--workers 1). Because flask-socketio does not provide sticky sessions.

Comment: By the way, I also used flask-socketio as websocket but was faced same issue. Later I switched to websockets library, It is working fine.